# py2exe: Generated EXE doesn't load

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe

My PyQt4 application's py2exe binary flashes briefly on the screen and then disappears. I have no idea why, but here's what happened before:

My application didn't display SVG images when loading (from the Exe), so I dug around a bit and saw that I had to modify my `setup.py` to include a `qt.conf` and some DLLs.

Then the binary just stopped loading after the `qt.conf` was included.

I played with the `qt.conf` and found that my Exe doesn't load *unless* I delete the `qt.conf`, so I think it is malformed.

Here's my `qt.conf`:

```
[Paths]
Plugins = plugins
```

I tried it with absolute paths, forward slashes, back slashes, you name it. I even copied the entire PyQt4 folder with this file and still no luck.

If it's relevant, here's my `setup.py`:

```
import os, sys, glob

from distutils.core import setup
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe

def find_data_files(source,target,patterns):
  if glob.has_magic(source) or glob.has_magic(target):
    raise ValueError("Magic not allowed in src, target")

  ret = {}

  for pattern in patterns:
    pattern = os.path.join(source,pattern)

    for filename in glob.glob(pattern):
      if os.path.isfile(filename):
        targetpath = os.path.join(target,os.path.relpath(filename,source))
        path = os.path.dirname(targetpath)
        ret.setdefault(path,[]).append(filename)
  return sorted(ret.items())

setup(
#  zipfile = None,
  data_files = find_data_files('', '', ['bin/*', 'plugins/iconengines/*', 'qt.conf']),
  windows = [{'script': 'main.py'}],
#  cmdclass = {'py2exe': Py2exe},
  options = {
  'py2exe': {
    'bundle_files': 1,
    'includes': ['sip'],
    'dll_excludes': ['MSVCP90.dll']#, 'qsvgicon4.dll']
  }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember right, Py2exe is discontinued, so it's really not safe to use.

I use cx_Freeze, which has never failed me once in working. It might help you out too.

Also, remember that paths are different when frozen vs a script. Typically, you need `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` for frozen (which you can test for using `hasattr(sys, 'frozen')`), vs a typical `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Also, make sure you're copying the `imageformats` qt plugin directory. It has caused problems for people before. The imageformats folder is where the svg plugin resides in as well. You'll also need to copy `PyQt4.QtXml` and `PyQt4.QtSvg` dll's/so's over as well (required by svg plugin).

My project has a build_binary.py file for cx_Freeze which autodetects the plugin directory and copies the required stuff over. It may help you out to [take a look at it](https://github.com/Roejames12/phantomjs/blob/master/python/pyphantomjs/tools/build_binary.py).

Comment: py2exe seemed a bit clunky, and cx_freeze worked well for me on Linux, so I'll give it another shot. I'll definitely look at your code, and since your project uses SVGs *and* works when compiled into a binary, I guess your code works! Thanks.